# Installing PCL module for Python 3.6 in Anaconda

Tags: python-3, anaconda, pcl

I am using Python 3.6 in Anaconda3 for Windows10(64) and would like to install PCL module. I tried `conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl` from (https://anaconda.org/sirokujira/python-pcl) and successfully installed 
`pcl: 1.8.1-hd76163c_1 conda-forge`
`python-pcl: 0.3.0-py36h0881630_0 sirokujira`
However, `import pcl` in python gives error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Answer (score 1):

Found solution from this link: https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/issues/155.

Generally speaking, Python-PCL requires OpenNI2.dll to work properly, so just add the OpenNI2 installation folder ("j:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Samples\Bin\" for my case) to the system PATH environment, and everything will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Neveroldmilk, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: could you please let me know which version of OpenNI2 is installed in your machine?

Comment: Didn't notice that. I just use the version bundled with PCL 1.8.1 All-in-one package.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl --channel conda-forge
```

I tried this and successfully installed python-pcl on my computer. `import pcl` runs with no error.